# I want to achieve something like multiple circularimageview's overlapping each other, just like the google plus community page

Tags: java, android

[something like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phtxB.png)

I want to achieve something like multiple circularimageview's overlapping each other, just like the google plus community page

Comment: Probably by trial, study, error, try again. Like in: hard work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the imageview 100X100 its all about the layout margin:
You can use margin like this:

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/samplepic" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/samplepic" />



    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/samplepic" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/samplepic" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/samplepic" />

</FrameLayout>
```

for the circular image you can add this in gradle

> compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'